# i want to add values of a column of tables from 1st day of the selected month till the selected date.OR simply i can say i want to calculate MTD?

Tags: php, mysql, php-5.3

i have no idea about the code...

database is something like this..

```
id  mgeneration  igeneration   date

1    548711          541       2019-05-01

2    54879           522       2019-05-04

3     5448           104       2019-06-01

4     5585           207       2019-06-05

5     4848           764       2019-06-09
```

output will be like--
if i select date 05-06-2019 then in month 06 values of `igeneration` and `mgeneration` will be added from 01-06-2019 to date 05-06-2019
so output will be `sum = 311` for `igeneration` and `sum = 11033` for `mgeneration`

Comment: So create a WHERE clause that selects all records with a date between the first of that month, and the actual target date, and SUM() up the values of the two columns …?

Comment: What version of mysql are you on? AND do search for mysql cumulative total.

Comment: @04FS can you give the exact query, it'll be helpfull

Comment: No, helpful would be if you made an actual effort and tried something - so please do that! This is not a code-writing service, the initial effort has to come from you.

Comment: @04FS i asked for help not for advice, so thank you... and besides i wrote the query  i just wanted to be sure there areother way....  here is the query  see below

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "select sum(mgeneration) as sum_mgeneration, sum(igeneration) as sum_igeneration, from plant_data WHERE (date between '$start_date' and '$date')";`
```

where `$start_date =  date('Y-m-01', strtotime($date));`
and `$date` is selected date